# Concurrent.futures Problems

Tags: python, concurrent.futures, modulenotfounderror

So I have this code that needs to use Concurrent.futures module and for some reason it is telling me it does not exist. I have looked it up and I can not find what the problem is. I have tried installing the tools I need from it thinking that was the case but I can only get one of them to download.
Error message:

> from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'concurrent.futures';
> 'concurrent' is not a package

my code:

```
import requests, time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

sites = ["http://www.youtube.com"]

def get_one(site):
    resp = requests.get(site)
    size = len(resp.content)
    print(f"download {site} bytes from {site}")
    return size

def main():
    total_size = 0
    start = time.perf_counter()
    with ProcessPoolExecutor as exec:
        total_size = sum(exec.map(get_one, sites))
    end = time.perf_counter()
    for site in sites:
        
        total_size += size
        #print(f"downlded {size} bytes from {site}")
    #end = time.perf_counter()
    
    print(f"elapsed time: {end - start} seconds")
    print (f"downloaded a totla of {total_size} bytes")
    
    
if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

I know that normally there should be a file when I say "from" but everything I look up says concurrent.futures is a part of python, but for some reason mine will not work properly. If it is out there do I have to install it?

Comment: if go to the terminal, run `python -v` and then type `>>> import concurrent` you would see something like this `# code object from '/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/concurrent/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-38.pyc'
import 'concurrent' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fadd1320430>` can you pls check this?

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had a file named concurrent.py in my folder that was messing everything up!